# Transfer from set of buttons to other set of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change a set of buttons to other buttons. To which buttons it changes depends on the button that is chosen.

- Button1: 
  when clicked both buttons are replaced by the buttons: Button1a and Button1b
- Button2: 
  when clicked both buttons are replaced by the buttons: Button2a and Button2b

So far I got:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="buttons1-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn1">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn2">Button 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons1a-b">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn1a">Button 1a</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn1b">Button 1b</button>
  </div>    
  <div class="button2a-b">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn2a">Button 2a</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn2b">Button 2b</button>
  </div>    
</div>
```

And I've hidden the 1a-b and 2a-b buttons:

```
.button1a-b {
    display: none;
}
.button2-b {
    display: none;
}
```

But I'm struggling to create the JavaScript code for this.
Could someone help me in how to code this in JavaScript? Also, if there is a better way to write my HTML/CSS for this, please let me know.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, we can help you build upon that code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey after your reply I wanted to look up the answers I did not understand in order to show you. After reading them again I suddenly got some ideas and tried it. It worked..! Sorry for being such a noob!

Comment: No problem. Sometimes a second read after a rest helps. I have so few questions because I rest. A lot. ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how it may be done using `onClick()`

```js
function buttonPushed(btn) {
  var replacewith = "buttons1a-b";
  if (btn.id == "btn2") {
    replacewith = "buttons2a-b";
  }

  var allChildren = document.getElementsByClassName('buttons')[0].children;
  for (var i = 0; i < allChildren.length; i++) {
    var child = allChildren[i];
    if (child.className != replacewith) {
      child.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      child.style.display = "inline";
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.buttons1a-b {
  display: none;
}

.button2a-b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="buttons1-2">
    <button id="btn1" class="btn btn1" onclick="buttonPushed(this)">Button 1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn2" onclick="buttonPushed(this)">Button 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons1a-b">
    <button class="btn btn1a">Button 1a</button>
    <button class="btn btn1b">Button 1b</button>
  </div>
  <div class="button2a-b">
    <button class="btn btn2a">Button 2a</button>
    <button class="btn btn2b">Button 2b</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best option, but it will work for what you want.
Essentially i created an event listener for a click of the each button. Then just display the hidden buttons and hide the current.

```js
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  changeButtons(document.getElementsByClassName('buttons1a-b'), 'block');
  this.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('btn2').style.display = "none";
});
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  changeButtons(document.getElementsByClassName('button2a-b'), 'block');
  document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = "none";
  this.style.display = "none";
});

function changeButtons(coll, display) {

  for (var i = 0, len = coll.length; i < len; i++) {
    coll[i].style["display"] = display;
  }
}
```

```css
.buttons1a-b {
  display: none;
}

.button2a-b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="buttons1-2">
    <button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn1">Button 1</button>
    <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn2">Button 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons1a-b">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn1a">Button 1a</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn1b">Button 1b</button>
  </div>
  <div class="button2a-b">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn2a">Button 2a</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn2b">Button 2b</button>
  </div>
</div>
```